# New to Android, stuggling to write to .csv file on external storage

Tags: android, android-external-storage

Android 4.4.4
Writing a simple app to learn basics of Android programming.
Running a debug build (on my device not in emulator), both in USB debug from Android Studio, and also on the device after disconnecting from USB.

I simply want to write text data to a text file on external storage. Don't care at this stage if it is internal storage or SD card (there is an SD card installed).

I HAVE got WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission set in my manifest.
I AM checking that external storage is mounted - it is.

I have tried the code I found [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374379/impossible-to-create-file-on-external-storage-android)

```
File file = new File(myContext.getExternalFilesDir(null), "state.txt");
  try {

 FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file, true); 
 OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
     out.write(data);
 out.close();
}
```

I log filename to LOGCAT and it appears as
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.amazed.matthew.brunel/files/file.csv

which looks reasonable. There is no exception thrown, code runs fine, just no file created!! So, is a file being created somewhere else because I'm in debug, or what? Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: 1) What is it - `state.txt` or `file.csv`? 2) What is `data`?

Comment: ps.: csv file is a very bad alternative for Android. There're much better data storage like SQLite and SharedPreferences

Comment: @Budius - code snippet is pasted from link given. My filename is as per full path /stor....../ file.csv.  Chose csv because flat file suits the app and data does not need to be indexed, so should be compact and fast.

Comment: not indexed, compact and fast. Google for "android sharedpreferences". And I repeat `*.csv` is a very bad option for Android.

Comment: Happy to told why csv is bad - but so far you are not telling me!!!

Comment: It's not bad in the sense that will do damage, but it's just annoying and counter productive to manage Files, InputStreams, OutputStream and parse csv data on Android, whilst on the other hand, using a Shared Preferences you can super easily call `int number = sharedPref.getInt("number", 0);` or `shardPref.edit().putInt("number", number).apply();` without worrying about anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I don't fully understand why behaviour is as described below, but basic issue is **solved.**

I powered down the device and rebooted - next time I connected the USB cable and looked in Windows Explorer on my host debug machine....there were my files. So I don't know why I can't see them without power cycling the device, but they are there. **Weird!!**

Comment: That's happens because the MTP connection (USB connection between the Android device or emulator and the PC) is not a direct connection to the Android file system, but more like a bridge to the file system that does some caching in between. So rebooting the device you refresh this cache. Checking the file using some type or File Manager or the terminal is a direct access and won't have this issue.

Comment: @Budius - What's still strange is that I have two test devices and they behave differently. Motorola phone on 4.4.4 is what I described, but Samsung tablet on 4.4.2 does not! Everthing is visible on the Samsung immediately. Won't be a problem in the finished app - just a tad awkward during development. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but as far as I remember, the SD card on Samsung devices is a direct connection to the file system. They behave just like a USB flash drive. Yes, the world of Android is full of those weirdness. That's part of the fun to develop for it

Answer (score 0):

Following [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) example from Android Documentation you can do:

```
void write() {
    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "state.txt");

    try {
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        os.write(data);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w("ExternalStorage", "Error writing " + file, e);
    } finally {
        os.close();
    }
}
```

Without using `OutputStreamWriter`, also keep in mind that according to documentation:

> Starting in KITKAT, no permissions are required to read or write to
>   the returned path; it's always accessible to the calling app. This
>   only applies to paths generated for package name of the calling
>   application. To access paths belonging to other packages,
>   WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and/or READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE are required.